# Optional field for DateTime in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2012

I am wondering if it is possible to make Day field optional for any of the Date data types in `SQL Server 2019`?

For example the user may enter a date in `mm-yyyy` format e.g. 10-1980 or `dd-mm-yyyy` format e.g. 25-10-1980.

**1.** Is it possible for `smalldatetime`, `datetime`, `date`, `datetime2` or `datetimeofset` data types of SQL Server?

**2.** If not, I think the only option is to store these values via `nvarchar` data types?

Comment: As far as I know you can not store "partial"-dates (mm-yyyy)  in date-datatypes and for non-ISO formats (25-10-1980,25/10/2018) there are specialfunctions to convert them,e.g. CONVERT or TRY_CONVERT

Comment: Thanks. What is the purpose of these functions? As a result will I keep the data in mm-yyyy) format as `varchar`?

Comment: There is no "day field" in the date format. A date is a single number that does not have a format. If for some reason you want to preserve the exact format in which the user entered the date, then you have to use a string, although I am not convinced that [you want it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) in the first place.

Comment: If it was me, rather than using varchar I would use a date, always set day of month to 01, and disregard it. Or possibly tinyint month and smallint year columns. varchar dates are crummy.

Comment: I advice against `nvarchar` for dates. If you need to query db kind of "3 months ago" or "how many months" with sql, store date as `date`.

Comment: If you are only storing the month and year, and want a date and time data type, why not just store all the dates as the 1st of the month? Then your presentation layer can handle the formatting to be `mm-yyyy` or similar. Though you *could* store the month and year separately, this becomes a real pain when you want, say, rows before or after June 2020 (as it's *not* `Month <=6 and Year <= 2020`)

Comment: If you store user-input as entered, you are guaranteed that invalid values will be stored in your database. That will vastly complicate every attempt to make useful information of it when queried.

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you. Actually I also thought to set the 1st instead of null day values. But in order to distinguish real 1st and empty 1st days, we need to set them null. For this reason using string (varchar) seems to be a good option for us. Regards to all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest storing the results for the month as the first of the month.  An easy way to do this is:

```
select try_convert(date, right('01-' + @date, 10), 105)
```

The `'01-'` would be the first day of the month.

If you actually need to distinguish MM-YYYY and DD-MM-YYYY inputs, then you will need to use a string.